# Test Case and Testing Automation for Module Level Testing of Embedded C Projects

Tags: testing, tdd, automated-tests, code-testing

I am working on a automotive project which has different modules for different functionalities. Each module has a set of predefined APIs used to achive the functionality that it is intended for. (If you know about AUTOSAR and its modules, I am talking about the same).

I am working on a Watchdog module. Its functionality and the APIs are predefined. The module development consists of static code and generated code (configuration). Static code is written in Embedded C which realises the functionality of the module. The generated code consists of two files- "Cfg.C" and "Cfg.h". "Cfg.h" has macros and pre-compile options. "Cfg.c" has values for the global variables and constants. These files are generated based on the XML configuration file.

Currently the module testing is done by writing manual test cases in C and compiling with the static and generated code. One test case is written for each functionality. These test cases consists of only predefined API calls and no internal APIs are used. Upon executing the test case it will give whether the result is passed or failed.

My task is to automate the test case generation and testing of this module. Test case generation is to generate numerous test cases to test the functionality and also all possible scenarios. Test case generation includes both generating test cases and configuration files and testing using a combination of these.

What are the different ways to automate the test cases and perform testing automation?

What are the best practices followed in the industry for test case automation and testing?

How industries do module level testing for verify the functionality of the module?

At the outset, are there any tools available for test case automation and testing automation for the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

When I was programming embedded C, I'd test the code using C++ Boost unit testing framework.  Of course not on the target, just on my development PC. This implied that I had to stick to the parts of C that worked both on the target platform (ARM something, built with some IDE called KEIL) and on my development PC (Ubuntu, GCC and Make).

I'd link each C-module against a test specific stub module, that implemented all missing symbols.  The unit test, the unit under test, and the stub would be compiled and linked to an executable, that could be used for TDD, CI and regression testing before the code got to the target hardware.  It is pretty much plain unit testing or, even better, TDD from there.

This was for consumer electronics that are developed under looser standards than what I know applies to automotive, so I guess you will have to adapt this approach to match your coding standards.